# ZF2: change view script from controller factory

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-controller

In ZF2, I have 2 helpers. A helper has a form, and a mapper to handle the database interaction. I pass these helpers to the controller using a controller factory. The controller handles phones and addresses of a party that is either a person or an organization. Because a party is a person or an organization, it has different data, so the controller factory also passes the object: PersonObject or OrganizationObject with the party-specific data into the controller.

The 2 helpers are the same for both party types. But in the view script, I want to show the party-specific data, and here is my problem: I need to change the view script based on the object that the controller factory passes to the controller. I thought of having two different controllers, but it's an overkill: the view script is 90% the same, except for that 10% party-specific info that comes from the database into the party object.

How to change the view script from the controller factory? By changing here, I mean slightly different html layout with the party specific data.

EDIT:

@Saeven suggested posting some code. At the moment, I decided to create `ViewModel` in the controller factory, prepare it accordingly, and inject it into the controller. But I'm not sure it's a good.

The Helper:

```
class ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelper extends AbstractRegistrationViewHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        FormInterface $form,
        ContactMechanismMapperInterface $contactMechanismMapper
    ) {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->mapper = $contactMechanismMapper;
    }

    public function saveToDb()
    {
        $this->mapper->save(
            $this->form->get('contactMechanismFieldset')->getObject(),
            $this->form->get('partyFieldset')->getObject()
        );
    }
}
```

The helper factory:

```
class ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelperFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    use MutableCreationOptionsTrait;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');

        if (in_array('phone', $this->creationOptions)) {
            return new ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelper(
                $formElementManager
                    ->get('Parties\Forms\Forms\ContactMechanisms\PhoneRegistrationForm'),
                $serviceManager
                    ->get('Parties\Mappers\ContactMechanisms\PhoneMapper')
            );
        } elseif (in_array('address', $this->creationOptions)) {
            return new ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelper(
                $formElementManager
                    ->get('Parties\Forms\Forms\ContactMechanisms\AddressRegistrationForm'),
                $serviceManager
                    ->get('Parties\Mappers\ContactMechanisms\AddressMapper')
            );
        } else {
            throw new ServiceNotCreatedException('wrong option type specified');
        }
    }
}
```

Controller that uses the helper:

```
class PartyDetailsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $phoneViewHelper;
    protected $addressViewHelper;
    protected $partyViewModel;

    public function __construct(
        ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelper $phoneViewHelper,
        ContactMechanismRegistrationViewHelper $addressViewHelper,
        ModelInterface $viewModel
    )
    {
        $this->phoneViewHelper = $phoneViewHelper;
        $this->addressViewHelper = $addressViewHelper;
        $this->viewModel = $viewModel;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $viewHelperForFormSubmission = $this->getViewHelperForFormSubmission(
                $request->getPost('submitButton')
            );
            $viewHelperForFormSubmission->getForm()->setData($request->getPost());
            $viewHelperForFormSubmission->getForm()->setIsSubmitted(true);
            if ($viewHelperForFormSubmission->getForm()->isValid()) {
                try {
                    $viewHelperForFormSubmission->saveToDb();
                    $viewHelperForFormSubmission->getForm()->resetForm();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                $viewHelperForFormSubmission->getForm()->highlightInvalidElements();
            }
        }

        return $this->viewModel->setVariables([
            'phoneForm' => $this->phoneViewHelper->getForm(),
            'addressForm' => $this->addressViewHelper->getForm(),
        ]);
    }

    protected function getViewHelperForFormSubmission($submitValue)
    {
        if ($submitValue == 'phone') {
            return $this->phoneViewHelper;
        } elseif ($submitValue == 'address') {
            return $this->addressViewHelper;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('invalid submit argument');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for your helper, and how you are using it.

Comment: @Saeven, hey, thanks for the reply. Problem is that it's gonna be really a lot of code that's quite difficult to follow. that's why i kept explanation in words.

Comment: Just post your Helper and any Factory that builds it.  Your code will say 100x more than your paragraphs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After revisiting my question a little less than a year later, decided to share my experience, perhaps it would be of use to someone.

I went for different view scripts depending on the party type. What I did is I created a factory that creates an instance of a view model based on the type of party. It's absolutely OK to inject the view model from the controller factory into the controller. In fact, if you create a factory for the view model, you can reuse it as a part of some other module's view model by attaching it as a child of the main `ViewModel`. It is sometimes very useful if you need cross-module interaction.

I found out that the idea of `FormViewHelpers` isn't really great in my case because it adds unnecessary complexity and hierarchy because all what my `FormViewHelpers` did was to pass the call straight to the service or mapper. Just dependency-injected service (or mapper) and form into the controller did just fine for me. `FormViewHelpers`, are in principle not a bad idea IF(!) there's quite some logic to be put in.

Ah, and by the way, there's a great article by @yourcommonsense on www.phpdelusions.net that describes (im)proper use of try and catch blocks. It's main message is that use `try... catch...` when you have a certain scenario for recovering the error. Otherwise PHP itself is quite good with error reporting.

That's it. Good luck to someone who is in my previous shoes. :-)